# RxJs: Can you spread operators as arguments into pipe operator

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I have two observable streams which do very separate mapping logic, but then ultimately end with following 3 operators:

```
  this.selection
    .pipe(
      ..Custom mapping operators
      tap(_ => this.devicesLoading = true),
      switchMap(d => this.mapService.findLocationForDevices(d)),
      map(loc => marker([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
    )
    .subscribe(markers => this.plotMarkers(markers));
```

I want to move the last `tap, switchMap, map` operators to a common function so I can just apply these within both of my observable streams.

I thought of doing:

```
  private resolveLocationsAndConvertToMarkers = (devices: String[]) => [
    tap(_ => this.devicesLoading = true),
    switchMap((devices: string[]) => this.mapService.findLocationForDevices(devices)),
    map(loc => marker([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
  ];
```

But I wasn't sure how to spread these operators into the pipe arguments, like:#

```
      this.selection
        .pipe(
          // Custom mapping operators
          ... this.resolveLocationsAndConvertToMarkers
        )
        .subscribe(markers => this.plotMarkers(markers));
```

this errors that `there are no overloads that expect 3 or 5 arguments`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try use native `.apply()`

```
this.selection
    .pipe.apply(null,this.resolveLocationsAndConvertToMarkers)
```

or wrap the list of operator in `pipe()`

```
  private resolveLocationsAndConvertToMarkers = (devices: String[]) => pipe(
    tap(_ => this.devicesLoading = true),
    switchMap((devices: string[]) => this.mapService.findLocationForDevices(devices)),
    map(loc => marker([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
  );
```

or return higher order function

```
private resolveLocationsAndConvertToMarkers = (devices: String[]) => source=>source.pipe(
        tap(_ => this.devicesLoading = true),
        switchMap((devices: string[]) => this.mapService.findLocationForDevices(devices)),
        map(loc => marker([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
      );
```

Comment: Great thank you, all these worked. I went with the middle option for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this answer will help anyone else who stumbles across this question. The accepted answer did not exactly work for me, with the primary reason being `null` was passed as the first parameter for `.apply()` instead of my observable function again. Here is an example similar to what I successfully implemented in my project.

```
private pipeActions = [
   filter(...),
   map(...),
];

private myObservable = combineLatest(...);

doThing(): Observable<any> {
   return this.myObservable
      .pipe.apply(this.myObservable, [...this.pipeActions]);
}

doOtherThing(): Observable<any> {
   return this.myObservable
      .pipe.apply(
         this.myObservable,
         [...this.pipeActions, map(...)], // Do something additionally after my list of pipe actions
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a reactive approach (with no side effects unless really isolated):

```
const preSelection$ = this.selection
  .pipe
  //..Custom mapping operators
  ();

const selection$: Observable<Marker> = preSelection$.pipe(
  switchMap(preSelection =>
    concat(
      of(null),
      of(preSelection).pipe(
        switchMap(d => this.mapService.findLocationForDevices(d)),
        map(loc => marker([loc.latitude, loc.longitude]))
      )
    )
  ),
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
);

const isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = selection$.pipe(map(x => !!x));

const sideEffectUpdatePlotMarkers$ = selection$.pipe(
  tap(markers => this.plotMarkers(markers))
);

// isolate `subscribe` calls and side effects as much as possible
sideEffectUpdatePlotMarkers$.subscribe();
```